# Probability Question using Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

On average, an employee receive 25 emails each day, of which 60% are ‘spam’. What is the probability that the employee will receive exactly 15 ‘spam’ emails tomorrow?

My methodology is such:

$$
\frac {\lambda^{15}}{15!}e^{-\lambda} = \frac{15^{15}}{15!}e^{-15} = 0.1024 = 10.24\%
$$

I'm not certain about my answer. All I know is that, I have to use Poisson distribution.

**Additional content:**

I used binomial distribution to figure out the probability but the answer in this one is different from the one above. Not sure which method to rely on now.

$$
P(S=15)=\left(\begin{matrix}
        25  \\
        15 
        \end{matrix}\right)(0.4)^{15} (0.6)^{10} = 0.021 = 2.1\%
$$

Comment: This isn't right.  What you've given is the probability that the employee receives exactly $15$ e-mails.  But what you want is the probability that the employee receives exactly $15$ *spam* e-mails.  You'll need the principle that a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$, passed through a Bernoulli filter (that is, where some fraction $p$ of events pass through), yields another Poisson process with rate $\lambda p$.

Comment: After looking at your comment, I gave another go at the problem. This time, I got a different answer. Again, I'm feeling insecure about the new answer. @BrianTung

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: But I'm just concern about the unused probabilities given such as 0.60 and 0.40, which is why I tried using binomial distribution method for this problem but I'm slight baffled about whether or not I'm on the right path. I made some changes to the original post which pretty much explains to you what I've done. @BrianTung

Comment: The $0.60$ is being used: The $15$ is computed as $25\cdot 0.60$.

Comment: Your binomial expression is computing a completely different probability: It computes the probability that of $25$ total messages, $15$ are regular messages and $10$ are spam.  I think you've mixed things up there, but even if you had switched the $10$ and the $15$, it would still measure something different from what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binomial distribution as it was used in the question is not correct unless the distribution of the number of emails received in a day is not random; i.e., *exactly* 25 emails are received each day, and the probability that any given email is spam is exactly 60%.

If, however, we assume that the number of emails received in a day is a random variable $N$ which is Poisson distributed with mean $\lambda = 25$, the conditional distribution of the number of spam emails received on a given day with $N = n$ total emails is $$X \mid N = n \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n,0.6).$$  The unconditional distribution is therefore $$\Pr[X = x] = \sum_{n=x}^\infty \Pr[X = x \mid N = n]\Pr[N = n] = \sum_{n=x}^\infty \binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x} e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^n}{n!} = e^{-p\lambda} \frac{(p \lambda)^x}{x!},$$ which is of course itself Poisson with rate parameter $p\lambda$.  So the probability that $X = 15$ is simply $$\Pr[X = 15] \approx 0.102436.$$  In comparison, if $N = 25$ and we use the binomial model, $$\Pr[X = 15] \approx 0.161158.$$  (Your calculation is not correct because you've switched $p$ and $1-p$.)

Under a different distributional assumption for the number of emails received in a day, the answer will be different.  $N$ need not be $25$, nor does it need to be Poisson.  It could be negative binomially distributed; it could be uniform; it could be any discrete distribution whose support is a subset of the nonnegative integers.  The question as it is posed does not impose such a distribution nor does it imply one--it only supposes that its mean is $25$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Poisson distribution is applicable, this is correct. However there may be some uncertainty as to whether the Poisson distribution is really applicable. Are the spam emails recieved entirely at random, and independently?

Comment: It revolves on the assumption that the spams are random and independent of each other. So, your presumption is correct. @DavidQuinn

Comment: I used another probability technique but this time, it gives me a different answer. Refer to the original post. I've edited the contents there already so that you could have a look @DavidQuinn

Comment: The comments about your calculation by @heropup are right. In any event, you are assuming that the 25 is just an average so the Poisson distribution applies. Even if the 60% is also only an average, you can still use Poisson with $\lambda=25*0.6=15$, but the Binomial definitely doesn't apply unless n and p are fixed.